# Кража сессии (защита)

Tags: php, сессия

Добрый день пишу простой сайт. Пытаюсь избавиться от того что под одним логином и паролем могли сидеть 2 человека одновременно.
Прочитал что можно избавиться если создать ключ, записать в бд и каждый раз сравнивать. (как бы проблем нет)
Где-то написано что при каждом действие лучше менять, тоже нет проблем.
Но вот вопрос если я зашел под учетную запись и не делаю никаких действий. У меня подсмотрели к примеру сессию и подставили в у себя. Как бы все снова два пользователя.

**Какой способ защиты можно придумать от такой ситуации?**

У меня в голове только следующий велосипед:
При посещение страницы если неавторизован к примеру создаю рандомное сочетание и пишу в бд.
Далее при авторизации  вытаскиваю данный ключ и создаю еще один, обЪединяю их и в хеш. Его пишу в БД и в сессию.
и дальше проверяю при каждом действие.
Если кто то подсмотрел все такие сессию и заходит на сайт и вставляет себе то он не авторизовывается также форма авторизации.

Comment: Вы наверное не правильно понимаете значение слова перехват сессии - если её перехватили, то никакого логина и пароля вводить не нужно. Вариант только 1 - привязывать сессию к IP адресу, что будет болью для тех у кого нет постоянного внешнего IP адреса.

Comment: А что плохого в нескольких логинах? Например я на этом сайте залогинен в трёх разных браузерах и буду очень недоволен если меня будут заставлять перелогиниваться

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать SSL Сертификат. Даже бесплатный SSL FOR FREE